# How to add new rows into Tabulator table?

Tags: tabulator

When I add new rows into Tabulator, I use some object with default values:

```
var defaults =  { id: 11, country_id: 4 };
table.addRow( defaults );
table.addRow( defaults );
```

But Tabulator uses this object for data storage. Here all rows refer to the same data. Thus when one row is edited whole table is updated.

How to reproduce: open [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KES777/64pL0k3o/14/) and edit country column

What is correct way to add rows into Tabulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because objects are passed by reference, if you want to pass the same object in to multiple rows you need to deep copy it to break the reference using the `Object.assign` function.

```
var defaults =  { id: 11, country_id: 4 };
table.addRow(Object.assign({}, defaults));
table.addRow(Object.assign({}, defaults));
```

Answer (score 0):

As workaround I do next:

```
var defaults =  { id: 11, country_id: 4 };
var newRow =  {};
for (var attr in defaults) {
  newRow[attr] = defaults[attr];
}
table.addRow( newRow );

newRow =  {};
for (var attr in defaults) {
  newRow[attr] = defaults[attr];
}
table.addRow( newRow );

newRow =  {};
for (var attr in defaults) {
  newRow[attr] = defaults[attr];
}
table.addRow( newRow );
```